# Curvature of an Embedded Curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, curvature

If one has a a compact Riemannian surface $\Sigma$ (ie. a Riemannian manifold of dimension $2$), the Ricci curvature can be written as

$R_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} R g_{ij}$.

In other words, the curvature can be expressed by one single function.  The scalar curvature is equal to double the Gaussian curvature $K$, so one can also re-write

$R_{ij} = K g_{ij}$.

Does this mean that the curvature of a smooth embedded close curve in $\Sigma$ is also determined by the Gaussian curvature $K$ for the surface by Gauss-Bonnet theorem?

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting. What sort of results do you want, say when the Gauss curvature is identically zero?

Comment: If $K =0 $, then integrating the curvature $\kappa$ of the curve around the whole closed curve would just give $2 \pi$?

Comment: Ar I see. But an embedded curve in a Riemannian surface might not bound a disk. If it does, there's the Gauss Bonnet formula.

Comment: If the embedded curve is smooth and closed, does it not bound a disk?

Comment: It does not have to be, think of the first copy of $\mathbb S^1$ in $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$.

Comment: How are you trying to deduce something concrete about a function *pointwise* from only its integral? Just consider different closed curves in the plane or sphere.